# How could I sort a file containing words and numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to sort a file which consists of multiple words and letters but can't seem to do it.

I have got this so far:

```
def footballPlayers():    
    file = open("footballNumbers.txt", "r")
    line = file.readlines()
    i = 0
    char = line[0]
    while not line[0].isdigit():
        i = i + 1

    footballName = line[0 : i - 1]
    footballNumber = line[i: ]

    print (footballName, footballNumber)

footballPlayers()
```

Nothing seems to print!

The file looks like:

```
Cristiano Ronaldo 7
Ander Herrera 21
Mario Balotelli 9
```

etc.

I need to get them the file sorted but dont understand why nothing gets printed also

Comment: `while not line[0].isdigit(): i = i + 1` will either loop forever or not loop at all.

Comment: Why not just split on the last space? `footballName, _, footballNumber = line.strip().rpartition(' ')`

Comment: The condition expression of a `while` loop has to depend on something that changes inside the loop, or the loop will run forever (or not at all), unless you have a `break` inside the loop that depends on something that changes inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

To sort the lines by the score, you will need a [key-function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-key-function) to extract the numerical score from a line:

```
def get_score(line):
    return int(line.split()[-1])
```

Then you can sort effortlessly:

```
>>> lines = ['Cristiano Ronaldo 7', 'Ander Herrera 21', 'Mario Balotelli 9']
>>> lines.sort(key=get_score)
>>> lines
['Cristiano Ronaldo 7', 'Mario Balotelli 9', 'Ander Herrera 21']
```

Comment: I'd have used a lambda for such a simple key function. OTOH, `get_score` is self-documenting.